# Use AWS SQS in Scala Play 2.4 reactive project

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, playframework, reactive-programming, amazon-sqs

I want to use AWS SQS in my Play 2.4 project.

There are two options at moment:

1. There is a SQS wrapper called https://github.com/kifi/franz which supports reactive way of using that. But it seems not quite popular on Github not sure how mature it is? Whether the developers will continue to maintain it.
2. There is Java SQS SDK, but it doesn't support Scala Future (reactive way). If I want to make it non-blocking, could I use Akka or?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used SQS yet but I did have a similar need for DynamoDB. I tried using a third party Scala specific library -- bad idea (buggy, bad api, missing features). In the end I wrapped the AWS Java SDK. Making it 'reactive' is pretty easy and is similar to most things you would do in Scala. Call the AWS functions within a Future body (Future {}) and use functional constructs to process the result (map, reduce etc..).